# Looping in R to extract data

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have an object in "R" called p_int. This is a list of 1599 peak intensity numbers.
Within every 8 values of this list is a monoisotopic peak. This peak is the most abundant (largest peak value) compared to the other 7 peaks.

Therefore what I'd like to do is write a loop which processes p_int in batches of 8.
So it will take the first 8 values, find the largest value and add this to a new object called "m_iso".
It will then continue, looking at values 9-16, 17-24, 25-32 etc.

Any advice or code in helping me achieve such a loop would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Stephen.

Comment: show your attempt... code is not magically generated in SO.

Comment: This might get you started: http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r#TOC-Loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By 1599 do you actually mean 1600? Because 1599 is not evenly divisible by 8. I'm going to assume this is true and offer the following:

```
m_iso <- sapply(split(p_int,rep(1:200,each=8)),max)
```

Or:

```
m_iso <- apply(matrix(p_int,nrow=8),2,max)
```

This will give you a vector of maximum values for each set of eight observations.